# Data race condition detected in sync.Map - Golang

Tags: dictionary, go, race-condition

I run a test using the `-race` go tool argument, outputting

```
--- FAIL: TestRaceCondition (0.00s)
    testing.go:853: race detected during execution of test
```

```
func TestRaceCondition(t *testing.T) {
    var map sync.Map
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            map.Store(strconv.Itoa(i), nil)
        }()
    }
}
```

I don't understand, because, according to the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map),

> Map [...] is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines without
>   additional locking or coordination.

Comment: You're not showing the full output of the race detector, which will show you _exactly_ where the conflicting reads and writes are happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The race is on `i`.  Fix by passing the value to the function instead of referring to the single local variable:

```
func TestRaceCondition(t *testing.T) {
    var map sync.Map
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            map.Store(strconv.Itoa(i), nil)
        }(i)
    }
}
```

Another option is to declare a another variable `i` inside the loop:

```
func TestRaceCondition(t *testing.T) {
    var map sync.Map
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        i := i  // each goroutine sees a unique i variable.
        go func() {
            map.Store(strconv.Itoa(i), nil)
        }()
    }
}
```